# Get library interface from dll

Tags: dll, interface, reverse-engineering

i have a compiled dll library but i have no documentation about it. There is a way to get the public interface of a dll (at least function names, params numbers and type).

Thanks

Comment: To retrieve this information, use PeStudio (http://www.winitor.com)

Comment: With Dependency Walker i found this is a C library... no more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to decompile it and analyze each function, its calling convention, parametrs count, parameters meaning (unless it comes with some PDB, but I doubt it), I've done something like this before, it's complicated work, but it can be done.

Comment: I'm tring o use IDA and decompile the library... however it seems to ben an hard work, i solve the param count and type but the meaning is not so easy.

Comment: You need to debug the application and put breakpoints at the selected functions to see where the calls are comming from (and reverse engineer the application itself too) and what are the parameters, deadlisting in IDA is useful, but you need to run it (unless the params are clearly visible in the application dump in IDA). Use debugger in IDA or OllyDbg v2. If you need more help, pm me (you can find my MSN in my profile page).

Answer (score 1):

In order to retrieve the public symbols (functions and variables) exported by a Dynamic-Link Library, one can use the well-known [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). Parameters and Types are only available when the associated PDB file is available (which does not seems to be your case).

Comment: Of course, things are different when handling a managed or unmanaged library. I supposed your case is unmanaged.

Comment: I get functions name, but I still have no informations about their parameters... The only alternative is reverse-eng that dll?

Comment: Should you have the associated Symbols File (PDB file - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd4f8bd1(v=vs.90).aspx ), you can load your library in a debugger and retrieve these details.

Comment: You could also browse the PDB using a PDB Browser like this one (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37456/How-To-Inspect-the-Content-of-a-Program-Database-P)

Comment: I haven't got any other file but an example exe (that uses that library) and the dll.

Comment: ok, then debug your example.exe and see how functions of the DLL are invoked and how the parameters are passed, this will clear the question of parameters numbers, return type, etc..

Comment: No! Just google on this issue. Using WinDbg, OllyDbg, etc one can debug any image file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the OLEViewer that comes with Visual Studio to view the TypeLib of the DLL if it is a COM library. This would give you the information you need.